# What of CMake CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT property?

Tags: cmake

What has become of the CMake `CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT` property used in the [`set_target_properties`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_target_properties.html) command? The CMake [Properties on Targets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-properties.7.html#target-properties) page doesn't mention it but it appears in some `CMakeLists.txt` files I've seen.

[Googling](https://www.google.com/search?q=CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT) for `CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT` doesn't seem to give much insight into this question. At best, links like [linux.die.net](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cmakeprops) document what this property is for:

> When a library is built CMake by default generates code to remove any existing library using all possible names. This is needed to support libraries that switch between STATIC and SHARED by a user option. However when using OUTPUT_NAME to build a static and shared library of the same name using different logical target names the two targets will remove each other's files. This can be prevented by setting the CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT property to 1.

And that seems like an important function!

[Searching for this property on cmake.org](https://cmake.org/?s=CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT) however, shows "no results found".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately, the cmake source code and its revision history can be found [online](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake). Searching the `git log` history, reveals a [commit](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/commit/430cc2b4b7a817be2fbc445d6803163f1695a533), dated May 1 2009 by Brad King, that sheds some light into this question.

This commit's log message is as follows:

> ENH: Always imply CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT target prop
>
> This property was left from before CMake always linked using full path
> library names for targets it builds.  In order to safely link with
> "-lfoo" we needed to avoid having both shared and static libraries in
> the build tree for targets that switch on BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.  This meant
> cleaning both shared and static names before creating the library, which
> led to the creation of CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT to disable the behavior.
>
> Now that we always link with a full path we do not need to clean old
> library names left from an alternate setting of BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.  This
> change removes the CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT property and instead uses its
> behavior always.  It removes some complexity from cmTarget internally.

Accordingly, the commit's source code changes show that functionality, documentation, and uses of `CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT` was removed.

Bottom line appears to be: **the CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT property has been removed and instead its behavior is always used**.